# Как работает параметр header в функции read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Не могу понять работу параметра `header` функции `read_csv()`.

Дайте, пожалуйста, пояснение его работы по скриншотам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `pd.read_csv` здесь не причём - вы просто передали параметру `header` конструкцию с синтаксической ошибкой:

```
print([0:2])
------------------------------------------------------
  File "<ipython-input-63-1c502b3dc513>", line 1
    [0:2]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Срезы можно применять к соответствующим объектам, например к спискам или кортежам. У вас же он сам по себе и Python не понимает такой синтаксической конструкции.

---

> я ещё хочу знать что именно такое параметр header и для чего он нужен

Параметр `header` используется для явного указания - какие строки считать заголовками (наименованиями столбцов). Например в том случае если в файле отсутствуют наименования столбцов - нужно использовать `header=None` - в этом случае столбцы будут пронумерованы: `0, 1, 2, ...`.

По умолчанию `pd.read_csv(...)` считает что первая строка CSV файла содержит наименования столбцов. Другими словами - значения параметра `header` по умолчанию - `1`.

Также Pandas поддерживает [многоуровневые наименования столбцов / multi-level columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) - в этом случае параметру `header` нужно передать список с индексами строк файла, в которых содержатся наименования столбцов (индексация начинается с нуля).

Comment: Я чуть опоздал, но вроде по-другому расписал, пусть будет )

Comment: @CrazyElf, конечно, у вас в ответе есть упоминание о `header=range(3)` - мне кажется это именно то, что нужно автору вопроса )

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение ошибки, но я ещё хочу знать что именно такое параметр header и для чего он нужен, извините, что некорректно задал вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Это просто список индексов строк, из которых нужно взять заголовок. Если много строк указать - будет multyindex, а не просто индекс в заголовке. Вы пытаетесь сделать питоновский срез, но срез делается от коллекции, просто так ниотчего его нельзя сделать, поэтому на последнем скрине у вас ошибка. В принципе, того, чего вы хотели добиться таким параметром, скорее всего можно сделать, если указать `header=range(3)`, это будет эквивалентно `header=[0, 1, 2]`.